# rollup throws missing warning on existing plugin-node-resolve option

Tags: svelte, rollup, plugin-node-resolve

I'm launching svelte with `npm run dev` after updating some packages and now I'm getting this warning:

```
WARNING: Your @rollup/plugin-node-resolve configuration's 'exportConditions' array should include 'svelte'. See https://github.com/sveltejs/rollup-plugin-svelte#svelte-exports-condition for more information
```

In my `rollup.config.js` I'm importing the relevant librariess:

```
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
```

I'm explicitly listing `'svelte'` in `exportConditions`:

```
export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        file: 'public/build/bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        ...,
        resolve({
            browser: true,
            exportConditions: ['svelte'],
            extensions: ['.svelte'],
        }),
        commonjs(),
        ...,
    ]
}
```

I'm currently working with `svelte 4.2.7`, `rollup 4.5.2`, `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve 15.2.3` and `@rollup/plugin-commonjs 25.0.7`.

Comment: i have same issue with svelte 4.x '__') downgrading svelte to 3.59.2 works